Automatically set From Email and Name before sending an Email from Magento
My current requirement is to use AWS SES to send emails from my Magento(2.4.7) project. Since AWS also requires the from email which is a verified identity on SES itself. When i tried to configure that in Stores->Configuration->Advanced->System->Mail Sending System it didn't have From Email and Sender Name. So i created a Custom module with following system.xml to add those 2 properties
etc/adminhtml/system.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="system" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="900" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <group id="smtp" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <field id="fromemail" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="121" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>From Email</label>
                    <comment>From Email</comment>
                    <depends>
                        <field id="transport">smtp</field>
                    </depends>
                </field>
                <field id="sendername" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="122" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Sender Name</label>
                    <comment>Sender Name</comment>
                    <depends>
                        <field id="transport">smtp</field>
                    </depends>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>

After this when sending email through following code it works fine and i am able to send email
private function sendContactAlert($post){
        $fromEmail = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('system/smtp/fromemail',ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        $fromName = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('system/smtp/sendername',ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        $from = ['email' => $fromEmail, 'name' => $fromName];
        $templateData = [
            'name' => $post['name'],
            'message' => $post['message'],
            'email' => $post['email'],
            'phone_no' => $post['phone_no']
        ];
        $this->transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier('techneat_contact_email_template')
                ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID])
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => new DataObject($templateData)])
                ->setFromByScope($from)
                ->addTo($this->contactsConfig->emailRecipient());
        $this->transportBuilder->getTransport()->sendMessage();
    }

But i dont want to load the From Email everytime from settings before sending emails. If i do that it makes the custom module that i built as a required module for whatever solutions i implement. Is there anyway to configure magento to use the above properties to load the values from settings and apply it before sending email in my custom module?
Btw i did try Mageplaza Smtp plugin and it didn't even work and crashed Magento admin after installing via composer as recommended. Had to disable it
Thanks in advance

I found a solution, hopefully helps someone. Issue was from email was missing when sending email through TransportBuilder using my custom module. Fixed it using a plugin. Below is my code
di.xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder">
        <plugin name="custom_email_identity" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\TransportBuilderPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>

TransportBuilderPlugin
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class TransportBuilderPlugin
{
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function aroundGetTransport(
        TransportBuilder $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    )
    {
        $fromEmail = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('system/smtp/fromemail', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        $fromName = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('system/smtp/sendername', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        $from = ['email' => $fromEmail, 'name' => $fromName];
        $subject->setFromByScope($from);
        return $proceed();
    }
}

This code will set fromEmail and Sender Name globally. Whenever an email is sent using TransportBuilder it attaches fromEmail and Sender Name from settings.

Magento 2 Providing you to set different "Sender Name" and "Sender Email" from the configuration it self.
For that:

Go to Stores > Configuration > General > Store Email Addresses.
Enter the Sender Name and the Sender Email

Now use that as Sender of your custom email as well.

Sorry if the question is feels like a beginner cuz i am. I saw that option. Lets say in Custom Email one i set my email and sender name, how can i set Custom Email One as the default sender in my Mail sending settings?

You need to do code like this only $this->transportBuilder->setFrom($from)

i have implemented that in the above code. But my question is to set the from email globally. Dont want to set it everytime i send email with transportBuilder

@karthik nk
Hey,
Step 1: Create or Update the Custom Module
If you already have a custom module, you can add the observer to it. If not, create a new custom module.
Directory Structure
app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/
1.1 Create registration.php
php

<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'YourVendor_YourModule',
    __DIR__
);
1.2 Create module.xml
xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="YourVendor_YourModule" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>

Step 2: Create the Observer
Create an observer to listen for the email_send_before event, which is triggered before an email is sent.
2.1 Create events.xml
Create the events.xml file in the etc directory to declare the observer:
xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="email_send_before">
        <observer name="yourmodule_set_from_email_and_name" instance="YourVendor\YourModule\Observer\SetFromEmailAndName" />
    </event>
</config>

2.2 Create the Observer Class
Create the SetFromEmailAndName.php file in the Observer directory:
php

<?php
namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class SetFromEmailAndName implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();

        // Set your custom From Email and Name
        $fromEmail = 'custom@example.com';
        $fromName = 'Custom Name';

        $transport->setFrom([
            'email' => $fromEmail,
            'name' => $fromName
        ]);

        return $this;
    }
}

Step 3: Run Setup Upgrade
After creating the observer, run the following commands to ensure that Magento recognizes your new module and applies any necessary updates:
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento cache:clean

Step 4: Verify the Changes
To verify the changes, perform an action in Magento that triggers an email, such as placing an order or creating a customer account. Check the "From" email and name in the received email to ensure they are set as specified.
Thank You!
